# I receive "You are now authenticated with Tabnine" for vscode but it does not sync

Tags: synchronization, vscode-extensions

[It remains like this and won't change Idk if it's a bug and I'm synced or I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnUjR.png)

[It does not change after it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Edt.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of DNS I was using. With disabling the DNS it was fixed.